# Object literals to select specific components react/typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Is it possible to use object literals with enums to return different components in Typescript/React?

If not, why does this pattern not work?

```
enum ItemType {
  TASK,
  NOTE,
}

function NoteComponent(props: { type: ItemType.NOTE }) {
  return <div />;
}

function TaskComponent(props: { type: ItemType.TASK }) {
  return <div />;
}

function getComp(type: ItemType): typeof NoteComponent | typeof TaskComponent {
  return {
    [ItemType.NOTE]: NoteComponent,
    [ItemType.TASK]: TaskComponent,
  }[type];
}

const noteProps = { type: ItemType.NOTE };
const taskProps = { type: ItemType.TASK };

function App() {
  const Comp1 = getComp(noteProps.type);
  const Comp2 = getComp(taskProps.type);

  return (
    <>
      <Comp1 {...noteProps} />
      {/**
        Type '{ type: ItemType; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        The intersection 'IntrinsicAttributes & { type: ItemType.NOTE; }
        & { type: ItemType.TASK; }' was reduced to 'never' because
        property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
        ts(2322)
      */}
      <Comp2 {...taskProps} />
      {/**
        Type '{ type: ItemType; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        The intersection 'IntrinsicAttributes & { type: ItemType.NOTE; }
        & { type: ItemType.TASK; }' was reduced to 'never' because
        property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
        ts(2322)
      */}
    </>
  );
}
```

**Update:**

How do you set `ItemType.NOTE as const` when the values are being returned from an API rather than hardcoded?

```
const apiResponse = [
    { type: ItemType.NOTE, ...noteSpecificProps },
    { type: ItemType.TASK ...taskSpecificProps },
];


apiResponse.map(item => {
    const Comp = getComp(noteProps.type);

    return <Comp {...item} />;
});
```

Comment: Would something like `NoteComponent(props: { type: ItemType })` work?

Comment: I want to use the enum values to select the components. So `<NoteComponent type={ItemType.TASK} />` should error.

Answer (score 3):

1. `getComp` function should return specific component according to provided type (instead of union). This can be achieved with overloads or generics.
2. In object literal `{ type: ItemType.NOTE }` the `type` is widened to `ItemType`, to prevent this [`as const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) can be used.

---

```
const componentMap = {
  [ItemType.NOTE]: NoteComponent,
  [ItemType.TASK]: TaskComponent,
}

function getComp<T extends ItemType>(type: T) {
  return componentMap[type];
}

const noteProps = { type: ItemType.NOTE } as const;
const taskProps = { type: ItemType.TASK } as const;

function App() {
  const Comp1 = getComp(noteProps.type);
  const Comp2 = getComp(taskProps.type);

  return (
    <>
      <Comp1 {...noteProps} />
      <Comp2 {...taskProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAOwFc8BJGJEAFQE8wk4BvcuOKwCCAZQDSAGn5wAcgHlWAUSkBfSplrUMwCNVkRmAYVyRqNGAAowOMAGcAXLzgxOSR0xYcuAOnlK4KgCUvNJEMLRQegA8ACbAAG5wAPQAfBRq5BpaMDp6rCi2ANbG4LrmVjYOTi5c7sxsrt7C4gHBfAJhEdFxianplGi6tvCDpWbUMACyKGBwALwhAgDaHg0%20fooAuo4yBkglpuZSy6teSE2iYtuCBcUmZROq6praunAA5kgwB1GscEgAD2Y1Bitjgp1cKQsNTcgjaoS%20XTgo0OE2mYCWMM2-XIg2owzg1D2AAVKvNqq46p5GhsAnACsihjAKHiCTBbqSIHZyTxnJTwfUzhcWip6WDWczntlcnAhGAwBZ4QIJXADgBGcmfb4mCxE5icuzeGGBCjKpmqkwAJk1XwO0I5lSNrhNlA6iMicAs0gEURS3oEcCi6t43lDeqQBtsotS-p9B2tPFDRodXKjyT9AcDMYELpUQA)

Comment: How would you set `ItemType.NOTE as const` within an interface?

Comment: e.g. when you are injecting props dynamically from elsewhere

Comment: Updated orignal question.